How to set default hidepid option on /proc mount
I have a virtual private server hosted in the cloud running Ubuntu 22.04, and I need to change the options with which /proc is mounted. Currently it gets mounted with the hidepid=2 option by default. However, this setting is incompatible with the Java virtual machine that DB2 uses to execute stored procedures written in Java, causing invocations of those procedures to fail. There is no entry in /etc/fstab for /proc, but I can add one with the hidepid=0 option and then do a mount -o remount /proc and the mount settings will change. But after a couple minutes the setting somehow gets changed back to hidepid=2, and the JVM stops working. Also, when the server is rebooted it is still hidepid=2 by default. What I need to find out is how the options for /proc are getting set at boot time and then reset periodically while the server is running.
